# SharePoint "connect to outlook" isssue

Tags: outlook

I have integrated Outlook 2007 with the SharePoint Team Discussion list.If I manually drag and drop mail in to the discussion board mapped folder(inside outlook) it works. But when I set rules to move mail from inbox to the folder it does not move the mail and shows the following error:

> "Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x00000000) : 'Home - Test
>   Discussion Board - Failed to copy one or more items because some are
>   not compatible with SharePoint. The failed items were moved to your
>   Local Failures folder and replaced with copies from the server. If you
>   need assistance troubleshooting items in your Local Failures folder, a
>   Help topic is available at the following address:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70300. For details, see the log
>   file."

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @noocyte I also did not find any ways to solve this. I guess outlook does not allow to move mail to SharePoint folder via rules.So I followed other approach to read mail from outlook programmatically and insert in to SP List.